# maven javaee application client plugin

Tags: maven-2, jakarta-ee, application-client

I am pretty new to maven.

Is there any plugin or packaging type suitable for building application client jar file ?

I want to add the application-client.xml file to the META-INF folder inside the jar.

The normal jar packaging doesn't include the file.

Comment: Here it is: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-acr-plugin/ http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/using-app-client.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need to define the project with jar packaging (and as it is the default you don't need to declare it).
If you define the application-client.xml in the src/main/resources/META-INF folder it will be included in the META-INF folder of the final jar.

---

To define additional information you need to configure the jar plugin as below.

```
<project>
...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</mainClass>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
            <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Check out the [guide to working with manifests](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-manifest.html) for full details

Comment: It works well. Now how to add main class and classpath information to menifest ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the JavaEE support in Maven, but it looks like the ejb plugin can generate a client jar as well if configured properly.  Check this page out:

[Maven EJB Plugin - Generating an EJB client](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/generating-ejb-client.html)

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but doesn't seem to work. The application-client.xml is not included. Should I change the packaging ?

Comment: This just creates a 2nd artifact, with the client classes (eg. EJB interfaces) for inclusion in client applications.  These client applications could be WAR modules, or other application clients.  The 2nd artifact has the "-classes" maven classifier.

Comment: the OP might be talking about »Java EE Application Client« - that is an EJB with a main() which is executed by the container on deployment. Or not - the double use of client here is confusing.